# Wordpress Migrate Inline Images looking in wrong folder

Tags: 7, migrations, media

I've recently used the Wordpress Migration module to bring over a lot of posts into drupal. The images get moved, and the text comes in fine. The problem is when the images get brought over they are put in one location on the server, but the inline media tags tell them to use view_mode: media_large the images don't show in the post because it's looking in the '/sites/default/files/styles/large/public' folder instead of where they actually got imported to. How do I either import these posts so that the images go there, or so that the media tags that are created don't look in the large folder but where the files actually are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the styles folder inside /sites/default/files was the only folder in there that was not writable by the server so it put the images elsewhere. I rolled back the wordpress import, fixed the permissions, and ran the import again. Everything seems to be good now.